# How update one specific property to database,without overwrite to NULL the rest properties

Tags: database, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

i want update to databgase one of properties for UserData which have(name,street,city,etc)
so:

**Relationship & DB properties:**
This UserData have a bi-directional relationship with his User where cascade="save-update" on User.hbm.xml is used, so

*User* have this properties in DB (id_user, *Foreign key:* id_UserDetail, status)

*UserData* have (id_UserDetail,*Foreign key:* id_User, and classic info fields name,street,telephone,etc  )

I use this method to update to database:
**Update method**

```
public void ajaxNameListener(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {         

             UserData usrData = new UserData();
             userData.setName(name);  // I want update only name property,but unfortunately rest is also overwriten to null in DB

                 User user = BeanFactory
                        .getHotelDAOService(User.class)
                         .findbyIdIndetifier(selectedUserId);   // selectedUserId is just identifier from my list of user,so here i declared which concrete User be updated by Id of Users           

                    user.setUserData(userData);
          BeanFactory.getHotelDAOService(User.class)
                    .update(user);
}
```

This method is used as listener form `<a4j:>` on my Jsf page but there is no problem with this,

I need repair this method somehow to update only this DB field what i need and rest must be unchaged, but in this case i succesfully made change for example on field 'name' this update field name by particulary Id, but rest of UserData columns is overwriten to NULL,

Can somebody type me some advice how can be modify this method? or may write own method based on this case, which cause updating only this field what i want update,not rest to NULL in database, 
Thank a lot for yours post and response,
Cheers,

Comment: Can you try fetching `UserData` from database instead of creating new one.

Comment: hm, can you please more clarify me this? i try  update only single field, but method above also rewrite rest fields to null, e.g. i want update name, and other properties also being updated but to Null,somehow need update only single field,dont know how

Comment: @ViliDuarte1 how are you binding your database fields? can you show some snippets of jsf, hibernate-mapping files?

Comment: Hi ok i show that,but i think a mappings file is neccessesary becasue there is all fine,but can i show also no problem.see bellow there i put this information.wait please right now i create post and give you  better information about what i want

Comment: Nayan Wadekar says: you are getting the `User` details from `selectedUserId`..so you should be able to fetch the `userData` from DB..once you fetch the data...you can set the field you want to change and save it...

Comment: aha i will try also this,but right now i found some solution,dont know for sure that will be works, so if i put **update="false"** on property in hbm.xml then hibernate dont use generated field values in DB? dont know this attribute how works maybe is not good in my case,

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs because at the time you save/update User's instance, it doesn't have values to its FK properties. So FK properties' values become null.

To avoid this, you can follow either way mentioned below:

1. Instead of updating the instance using hibernate API, write an HQL to modify only the property you want to change. (e.g. name in your case.)
2. Load the instance of User from hibernate session, change value of the desired property in that instance, Update the User instance. All these 3 operations must be done in a single hibernate session.

Comment: Thank you for this option, i solved this puting dynamic-update="true" in hbm.xml file, but works like when i update e.g 'telephone'.a stacktrace occurs and tell that 'name' cannot be null(i have this set on NOT NULL in DB) so maybe still has overwrite a unmodified values like this 'name'