# How to update referenced entity in hibernate

Tags: hibernate

I have following tables

```
Question_Table:{
quesId int primary key,
statusid int reference to Status_Table.statuId
}


Status_Table:{
statusId int primary key
}

Answers_Table:{
index int primary key,
quesId int reference to Question_Table.quesId,
answerDescription varchar
}
```

1. Question have multiple Answers here: Question_Table--Answer_Table have One-to-Many Relationship.
2. Every Question have its status id: Question_Table--Status_Table have Many-to-One Relationship

Query: On update of answer in answer_table by end user i want to update its status : "Complete" in question_table, but when i fire update(answer) it only fire update on answer table (verified in logs) , i am confused with the situation as here i do not have direct relation between entities-- status and answer table.

Comment: As long as you are talking about tables and not objects, you are not using the actual power of an ORM.

Comment: say more words about the actual power, I thought i am using entities classes and its perfect orm in use???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to update `status_id` in Question's table by just doing `update(answer);`.

Firstly you need to fetch the record from Question table, that is associated with the answer.
After that you need to fire an update query to the fetched question record with the new `status_id`.

For example,

1. `update(answer);`
2. if answer.question_id = 1, then do: `select * from question where id = 1`
3. set status in question & then do: `update(question);`

Comment: I thought some inverse or cascade could do this thing ??

Comment: tried your way with update(answer.getQuestion()); which contains quesId and status entity object and is perfectly fine, but initiatedBy field of question entity is null and that is not required in updation either, but it is causing problem while update:not-null property references a null or transient value: com.hibernate.beans.question.initatedBy

Comment: That is a separate issue. For that issue see the links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15250751/how-update-one-specific-property-to-database-without-overwrite-to-null-the-rest/15264905#15264905 & http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-dynamic-update-attribute-example/

Comment: I used Exactly same HQL way because loading the entity from session was not possible in my case and its working fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When working with object within the Hibernate session (attached objects), you don't need to call update. Hibernate finds the changes.

pseudocode:

```
answer = session.CreateQuery("select ...")
answer.Question.Status = Completed;
session.Commit();
```

Changes are sent to the database on commit (or when flushing before queries).

Comment: Then you do something else. I can't help you with only the information that it is not working.